# Is it possible to make an existing Ubuntu installation completely free?

Tags: open-source, gnu, free-software

I was unaware in the beginning that Ubuntu is not completely free software, as  [it uses non-free components](https://www.gnu.org/distros/common-distros.en.html).

Is it possible to overcome the system's dependence on these (such as replacing Linux kernel by `linux-libre`) and make my current installation of Ubuntu 16.04 completely free software (assuming I do not make any non-free additions voluntarily)?

Comment: IIRC, everything in the `main` and `universe` sections is libre. It's `restricted` and `multiverse` that contain non-free software. So, remove anything installed from those sections of the repository.

Comment: Thanks, but what about the linux kernel? Is it possible to replace the existing image with a linux-libre image? (More:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux-libre)

Comment: Probably https://jxself.org/linux-libre/ might be of use.